# How to find a list of objects that do not have a relationship with another object in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have the following object structure:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Club(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)


class ClubMember(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member)

class Member(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
```

How do I find all the members for a customer that do not yet have ClubMember objects created?

The result would be a queryset of members.

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
Member.objects.attribute.exclude(id=clubmember_set__member_id)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking it up for a specific customer:

```
customer.member_set.filter(clubmember__isnull=True)
```

If you want all members that do not have ClubMember matches, regardless of customer:

```
Member.objects.filter(clubmember__isnull=True)
```

Comment: Or `clubmemeber_set__isnull`, assuming the default `related_name`?

Comment: @KevinHenry - to go into more detail - the `<foo>_set` name refers to a manager object as documented: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward .  In field lookups, the managers aren't involved - you just use the lowercased name of the related model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I never noticed this because I always give explicit `related_names` to these fields, in which case that name is used both for the manager and in field lookups.